# Making separator and button menu in customized Toolbar using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, add-in

How can I make a separator and button menu in customized Toolbar using ArcObjects?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

separator="true"

see

[ESRI Link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000007w0000000)