# Adding separator to ArcGIS python add-in menu?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

In several places (e.g. [Making separator and button menu in customized Toolbar using ArcObjects?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16568/making-separator-and-button-menu-in-customized-toolbar-using-arcobjects)) I have seen it mentioned that the way to add a separator for add-in menus and toolbars is adding the attribute `separator="true"` to the button in the config.xml file like: `<Button refID="test105_addin.button_1" separator="true"/>`.

However, I can only get it to work with ArcGIS 10.3 and not with 10.1/10.2.2.

Does anybody know how a separator is added using ArcGIS 10.1 (or 10.2.2)?

[image]

Comment: For Python AddIns I am currently doing it like that for 10.3.1 for separating buttons on a toolbar, and I am pretty sure that I did it the same way at 10.2.2.  However, I have not tried separating items on a Python AddIn menu.  What happens when you try to do it at 10.2.2 or 10.1 for buttons on a toolbar?

Comment: The same thing with separators on a toolbar, separators only shows up in 10.3. Maybe it has something to do with the add-in wizard. At one point I remember there came a new version of the add-in wizard I upgraded to.

Comment: Can you compare working config.xml from 10.3 with non-working config.xml from 10.2/10.1?  As far as I know the appearance of buttons, tools and menus is all defined there.

Comment: That sounds right. I see if I can find any differences

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have identified a bug that must have been fixed for ArcGIS 10.3.

If that is correct, and if it is critical for you to have this fixed for an earlier version, then I think your only option will be to leverage a Maintenance contract with Esri via their technical support to ask for that fix to be back ported, if that is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We just recently upgraded to 10.4.1 so it is not really relevant anymore - but maybe someone else will benefit from your answer.